# Magento CE 1.7 indexing timing issues with several cron jobs

Tags: php, mysql, magento, cron, indexing

I am using Magento CE and data is imported from 3rd party through Cron jobs with Custom scripts. Website catalog is more than 30K. The issue I am facing is with the indexing. As I need to run the Crons on daily basis and one(inventory update) on hourly basis, due to slow indexing, it is not possible to run the inventory update script on hourly basis as it takes around 25-30 minutes for the indexing. Same is the case with other cron scripts so I have to run one script per day. My requirement is to run all the cron scripts on daily basis. I have set the indexing mode to Manual mode because otherwise updating 30K rows takes forever.
I have tried few extensions to decrease the indexing time but in vain. Is there anything that can be done to decrease the indexing time significantly or is it possible that upgrading to Enterprise version will help solving this issue. This is critical issue as I need to sync the data real time with the 3rd party supplier but due to this indexing issue I cannot run all crons on daily basis resulting in data inconsistency with the 3rd party supplier data.
Suggestions and help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Kind regards
Cheema

Answer (score 1):

This extension (which is also free) really reduces the time it takes to reindex URL Rewites (by about 70-90%) by only reindexing what requires reindexing instead of the entire of the table of data.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dn-d-patch-index-url-1.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Magento EE 1.12 with over 80K products and this problem is still remaining, for reindex all tables it takes about 40/50 minutes, and the reindex of url tables is in a cronjob apart beacause it is the slowest (it takes about 20 minutes). My solution is to schedule catalog updates every day (maybe in the night) and after, run reindex of all tables except for catalog_url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reconsider to upgrade your server performance. That could improve the import time.
Or appServer / dbServer divided.